# Jquery not loading on ipad

Tags: jquery, ios, wordpress, ipad, testing

I have created a wordpress theme for a website I'm working on http://learntosmile.net which works fine on firefox, chrome and IE (IE badly but enough) but when I test it on ipad (original, only one I have at hand to test on) it seems that the jquery is not loading in correctly. The burger icon top doesn't load and the scroll to top does not load in at the bottom either.

Is there a way to output an error on ipad that I can test to see what the problem is?

Also worth mentioning it works on Chrome on ipad, just not safari.

**UPDATE**

I have changed `.click(function(){` to `.bind("click touchstart", function(){` and it slightly fixed the problem and now the scroll to top loads and the burger loads the menu, but it opens it and closes it instantly. Is this because it thinks the touchstart AND click are both done? I don't understand jquery very well.

Comment: I don't know. But Google knows :) https://www.google.com/search?q=debug+ipad

Comment: Yeah... No. I did that first, none of the links I found useful. I was hoping more for a way to check what errors might be thrown out like an inspect element.

Comment: Did you try Firebug Lite? It's a Firebug emulation in javascript that gets injected in the page, so you get it even on ipad.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyThille, I've sorted it now but it's nice to know there's such a thing like that to help in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having done some research I've found that `.bind("click", function(){` was enough to fix the problem of the burger opening and then closing the menu.

I'm not sure why `.click(function(){` had initially stopped jquery from loading, but hopefully if anyone else has this problem this fix will help them too.